# Assign a row name based on row contents

Tags: matlab

There is a set of names and a matrix(that it's elements are just zero and 1).
Every row of the matrix should be assigned to a name based on its value.

Let me give an example:
**Array is:**

```
[1 0 0;
 0 1 1;
 1 1 1]
```

**Set of names is:**
`Alex=[1 1 1], John=[1 0 0], Christine=[0 1 1]`

Output of function should return:

```
John, Christine, Alex
```

Is there any function in MATLAB that searches in this mode?

Comment: This sounds like a job for `ismember` but your question is unclear. Please provide a full example dataset. Don't use 44 columns reduce it down to like 3. Provide all inputs and manually computed outputs.

Comment: @Dan Ok Dan. I will edit the post now.

Comment: What is the structure of data underlying the set of names? Cells? Structs? Variables?

Comment: @samsam114 but `Alex=[1 1 1]` is defining a variable named `Alex`. That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Bentoy13 Here is just psudocode

Comment: @Dan Yes. That name of Variable is important here

Comment: @samsam114 provide ***EXACT*** output variable that you want, in a proper Matlab format. Is it a cell array of strings or what? Why would you name your variables like that, you are asking for trouble doing that. Rather keep a cell array of strings of the names and an array of keys that match those names row for row as in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example data make very little sense so I'm going to assume something different. Consider

```
Arr = [1 0 0;
       0 1 1;
       1 1 1;
       0 1 1];

Names = {'Alex';
         'John';
         'Christine'};
Key = [1 1 1;
       1 0 0;
       0 1 1]
```

then you can use `ismember` as follows:

```
idx = [~, idx] = ismember(Arr,Key,'rows');
Names(idx)
```

which will return

```
'John'
'Christine'
'Alex'
'Christine'
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly this is the case :). Regards Dan.